# Can't take a write lock while out of disk space

Tags: mongodb

Help me please!

My **C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.4.6\data** size is 8G. I have 95G free space of drive C. But I get this message:

> com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27017"
>   , "err" : "Can't take a write lock while out of disk space" , "code" :
>   14031 , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 10 , "ok" : 1.0}

The permissions are correct to write to data folder, because first few hours application works correctly.

What is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would check that the permissions are correct for `mongod.exe` to write to your data directory, and that the data directory is actually being used (in `mongo` shell, run `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` and verify the `dbPath` value matches "C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.4.6\data").

Comment: The issue is definitely related to space. Also, if this is your local machine and you are using it to do development then you could always start mongod with --smallfiles option. "mongod.exe --smallfiles" It takes less space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I used folder as a mapped drive on Windows.

I've replaced link to the link with absolute path on the real hdd and problem has gone.

It seems that mongo checks free drive space and compares its changes with created file size.

I don't understand the reason for downvotes...